# Implementing remove() Iterator Method in Java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, iterator, iteration

So I'm working with a generic LinkedList, and I need to be able to use an iterator to remove the second half of it. However, I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the iterator call:

```
    Iterator<String> itr = seq.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
    {
        itr.next();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
    {
        itr.next();
        itr.remove();
    }
```

And here's my iterator methods:

```
    boolean canRemove = false;
    int previousLoc = -1;
    Node<T> current = head;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return current != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next()
    {
        if (hasNext())
        {
            T data = current.getData();
            current = current.getLink();
            previousLoc++;
            canRemove = true;
            return data;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        if (!canRemove)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        SortedLinkedList.this.remove(previousLoc);
        canRemove = false;

    }
```

It gives a NoSuchElementException on the itr.next() call under the second for loop. My best guess is it may have something to do with the way I determine the previous node's location; the class DOES have a getPrevious() method:

```
private Node<T> getPrevious(T entry)
{
    Node<T> previous = null;
    Node<T> traverse = head;
    while (traverse != null)
    {
        //if(entry.compareTo((T) traverse.getData()) > 0)
        if (traverse.getData().compareTo(entry) < 0)
        {
            previous = traverse;
            traverse = traverse.getLink();
        }
        else
        {
            return previous;
        }
    }
    return previous;
}
```

And a getPosition method:

```
public int getPosition(T anEntry)
{
    Node<T> traverse = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < manyNodes; i++, traverse = traverse.getLink())
    {
        if(anEntry.compareTo(traverse.getData()) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element not in list");
}
```

However, if I try something like

```
SortedLinkedList.this.remove(getPosition((T) getPrevious((T) current)));
```

I get "solution.Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

Even though the class header does extend it:

```
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Iterable<T>
```

EDIT: Here's the remove method:

```
public T remove(int givenPosition)
{
    T dataToReturn;

    if (givenPosition < 0 || givenPosition >= manyNodes)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (givenPosition == 0)
    {
        dataToReturn = head.getData();
        head = head.getLink();
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> previous = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenPosition - 1; i++)
        {
            previous = previous.getLink();
        }
        Node<T> oneToDelete = previous.getLink();
        dataToReturn = oneToDelete.getData();
        previous.setLink(oneToDelete.getLink());
        oneToDelete.setLink(null);
    }
    manyNodes--;
    return dataToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Your `ClassCastException` is happening because `getPrevious` returns a `Node`, not `T`.

Comment: I do not really understand why would someone reinvent the wheel, and create a collection, as the Java Collection Framework has almost every imaginable collection types. A "Sorted List" makes no sense to me either...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto This is a homework assignment for CS II. Implementing remove() is worth a ton of extra credit so I'm dedicated to figuring it out

Comment: @teppic What can I do about that though? The "previous" and "traverse" fields in the getPrevious method have to be of Node since they call getLink(), so I can't really return anything other than Node

Comment: Try: `SortedLinkedList.this.remove(getPosition((T) getPrevious((T) current).getData()));`

Comment: I would be interested in your `SortedLinkedList.remove(int)` method....

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto That still gives "solution.Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable". Just added the remove method to the post

Comment: `current` is a `Node`, right? You can't cast it to `T`.

Comment: @teppic current is indeed a Node. I know that now, but still trying to figure out a way to get remove() working properly.

Comment: I think in your `Iterator`'s `remove()` you should decrement `previousLoc` as the `next()` calls increment it, but the `remove()` calls do not modify it...

Comment: I would suggest keeping the last returned node rather than its position. That way you can simply unlink the node in your remove method.

Comment: That would mean to implement (and maintain) the `remove()` method at 2 places...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Wow... you're right. I can't believe I missed something that simple. However, now I have another issue entirely: the assignment test is saying remove() takes too long.
"java.lang.AssertionError: Remove takes too long.
Removing from the front: 0ns.
Removing from the end takes: 156250000 ns." I really don't see how it's that inefficient. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Well, you have to traverse the list, so i do not think this could be done any significantly faster way, with your current data structure...

Comment: BTW check your assertion, to see what method was called, and how. And ask it in a new question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void remove()
{
    if (!canRemove)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    SortedLinkedList.this.remove(previousLoc--);
    canRemove = false;
}
```

As in your loop the calls of `next()` incremented the `previousLoc` while the `remove()` method removed the item from the list, it did not changed the value of `previousLoc`. Thus the `previousLoc`kept incrementing, while all elements were to be removed.

To see this in work, you should print out `previousLoc` during `next()` and `remove()`...

Comment: This logic works perfectly; however, for some reason the assignment test says remove() takes too long.  "java.lang.AssertionError: Remove takes too long. Removing from the front: 0ns. Removing from the end takes: 156250000 ns." It says it should always take constant time